# Angular two inputs syncing values that are -0.x

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I wonder if there is a better way to avoid angular not storing negative values that what I am doing here.

```
     <div>
        <input"
          [id]="highRangeId"
          [max]="1"
          [min]="-1"
          [step]="0.1"
          type="range"
          [formControl]="chromaBoostFormGroup.controls['High']"
          />
        <output class="range-output">15</output>
        <input"
          [id]="highNumberId"
          [max]="1"
          [min]="-1"
          [step]="0.1"
          type="number"
          [formControl]="chromaBoostFormGroup.controls['High']"
          />
     </div>

  this.chromaBoostSubscription = 
    this.chromaBoostFormGroup.controls['High'].valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
     if (this.chromaBoostFormGroup.controls['High'].valid){
       if (value != '-0' && value != '-0.' && value != '-.'){
         this.chromaBoostFormGroup.controls['High'].patchValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
       }
     this.changePoints();
     this.toggleRanges();
    }
  });
```

If I do not add this if value!=-0, while the user enter values when he enters -0, patchValue saves 0 and we lose the - sign

Comment: Zero is neutral, it has no negative or positive value

Comment: Thanks @TomaszVizaint. I know that but how can you solve the problem? The user is entering a value, for example -0.3, we have subscribe to valueChanges because we want to sync two inputs, when -0 is typed, we call patchValue and gets converted to 0. Then when the user continues typing .3, he ends up with 0.3 instead of -0.3

Comment: use `patchValue(+value)` -the "+" convert the string to number

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know what the purpose of your exercise is, but what I think is better to first collect the data entered by the user, and then modify it as you want, I have done a test and this is the result.

[image: Zeroway]

Update: do this chcnge in You code i recived this result now work in Firefox and chrome, If this helps you I'm glad :
[image: Zero2]

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want and it is my fault not having explain it better. I want to update both inputs and some plots (not shown in the example) as the user types/modifies any of them. Find Stackblitz link below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gfrxyn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome and Firefox and yes, in chrome I can put -0.2 without problem, in firefox as you say.